# Translating products: 1 and the same product in two different store views

Tags: product, configurable-product, multistore, store-view

we have a product that is sold in two separate store views.

**Question:** If I translate `product X` in `storeview store1->english` and also want it available in `store2->english`; do I then need to copy/duplicate the content? Or can we re-use the data from `store1->english`

**Our structure**

```
store: store1
storename: store1 -> domain1.com
storeview: store1 -> domain1.com -> french -> productA
storeview: store1 -> domain1.com -> english -> productA

store:store2
storename: store2 -> domain2.com
storeview: store2 -> domain2.com -> english -> productA
```

For *storeview:-> english -> productA* do we need to enter all attributes/description manually - or can we re-use what we used under *storeview:-> english -> productA* easily ...

Hope this is clear ;P thx